# How do i sort magento products collection with ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: magento

i have a custom product attribute with actually three possible values
"Frühjahr/Sommer", "Herbst/Winter", "" (empty).

I want to sort the product collection by this value in a predefined order
e.g. "Frühjahr/Sommer", "Herbst/Winter", "" OR
"Herbst/Winter", "Frühjahr/Sommer", ""

This is alternating.
The empty values should be allways at the end but maybe there are more values to come so it must be a fixed predefined order.

I need to execute the following MySQL
ORDER BY FIELD (saison, "Frühjahr/Sommer", "Herbst/Winter", "")

The problem is i have no clue how to execute this command in Magento. 
I know the "->setOrder"-Method but i need to commit a fixed order instead of using DESC or ASC.

I search a lot on stackoverflow and google but no answer so far.

I hope you can help me

Thanks

**[edit in responds to the answer of magalter]**

unfortunately it doesn't work i tried it before:

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(season, 'Frühjahr/Sommer','Herbst/Winter','')"));
```

The result is "There has been an error processing your request.

```
$this->_collection->getSelect();
```

return:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='124' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY FIELD(season, 'Frühjahr/Sommer','Herbst/Winter','')
```

I executed this sql-statement in phpMyAdmin and get the following error message "Unknown column 'season' in 'order clause'"

If I order by "season" DESC

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('season', 'DESC');
```

it works ... and generate the following sql-statement

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF(season_option_value_t2.value_id IS NULL, season_option_value_t1.value, season_option_value_t2.value) AS `season` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='124' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `season_t1` ON e.entity_id=season_t1.entity_id AND season_t1.attribute_id='180' AND season_t1.store_id=0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `season_t2` ON e.entity_id=season_t2.entity_id AND season_t2.attribute_id='180' AND season_t2.store_id='1' LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `season_option_value_t1` ON season_option_value_t1.option_id=IF(season_t2.value_id > 0, season_t2.value, season_t1.value) AND season_option_value_t1.store_id=0 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `season_option_value_t2` ON season_option_value_t2.option_id=IF(season_t2.value_id > 0, season_t2.value, season_t1.value) AND season_option_value_t2.store_id=1 ORDER BY `season` DESC
```

But this is order by DESC not by a predefined order like i want it so i can't use it.

What i need is the SQL Statement above with

```
ORDER BY FIELD(season, 'Frühjahr/Sommer','Herbst/Winter','')
```

instead

```
ORDER BY `season` DESC
```

Another idea ???

Comment: Why your $this->_collection->getSelect(); example differs so hugely from $this->_collection->setOrder('season', 'DESC'); ?
You need to connect all needed fields to collection, then make $this->_collection->getSelect();

Comment: This is a good question. I think the Magento "setOrder"-Method ensures that all needed fields are connected. But with the detour of "getSelect()->order(...)" i have to care about it. But honestly i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: Please, insert your source code, with joins, etc

Comment: Just Magento build-in functions, no own SQL. class "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar" method "setCollection" The SQL-Code for the Collections is generated by Magento.

Comment: you must also check if $this->_collection has your joined fields (season, etc). May be this function is called several times. Creation and setting of additional flag will help.

Comment: You have to reference the `main_table` typicially called `e`. Try:
`$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.season, 'Frühjahr/Sommer','Herbst/Winter','')"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly I have found a solution.
Maybe another user needs it so here it is:

(Probably not the best solution, but it works)

I created a new Modul and extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar.
Then i override the "setCollection"-Method like this

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $mySource = $this->_collection->getEntity()->getAttribute('season');

        $mySource = $this->_collection->getEntity()->getAttribute('season')->getSource(); //Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
        $collection = $this->_collection;
        $valueTable1    = 'season_t1';
        $valueTable2    = 'season_t2';

        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array($valueTable1 => $mySource->getAttribute()->getBackend()->getTable()),
                "e.entity_id={$valueTable1}.entity_id"
                . " AND {$valueTable1}.attribute_id='{$mySource->getAttribute()->getId()}'"
                . " AND {$valueTable1}.store_id=0",
                array()
            )
            ->joinLeft(
                array($valueTable2 => $mySource->getAttribute()->getBackend()->getTable()),
                "e.entity_id={$valueTable2}.entity_id"
                . " AND {$valueTable2}.attribute_id='{$mySource->getAttribute()->getId()}'"
                . " AND {$valueTable2}.store_id='{$collection->getStoreId()}'",
                array()
            );
        $valueExpr = $collection->getSelect()->getAdapter()
        ->getCheckSql("{$valueTable2}.value_id > 0", "{$valueTable2}.value", "{$valueTable1}.value");

        Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
            ->addOptionValueToCollection($collection, $mySource->getAttribute(), $valueExpr);

        $sortBySeason = "FIELD(IF(season_option_value_t2.value_id IS NULL, season_option_value_t1.value, season_option_value_t2.value), ";


        $getSelectedSeason = Mage::getStoreConfig('sortproductsbyseason_options/general/current_season');

        if($getSelectedSeason == "herbst_winter"){
            $sortBySeason .= "'Frühjahr/Sommer', 'Herbst/Winter' ,''";
        }else{
            $sortBySeason .= "'Herbst/Winter', 'Frühjahr/Sommer' ,''";
        }
        $sortBySeason .= ") DESC";

        $this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr($sortBySeason));

        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to use Zend_DB_Select order rather then Magento setOrder method

```
$colection->getSelect()->order(..)
```

Example:

```
->order(array('line_items_per_product DESC',
                       'product_id'));
```

See
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.order
for more examples

Comment: Thanks for your reply magalter. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I added more details to my posting see above.

Answer (score 0):

What about this??

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

Comment: i don't get it. Your code sort the collection by name ASC. This is not what i want to do. Or did i miss something?

Comment: This should be an example to show you, that you can use the methode addAttributeToSort when working with collections. ;-) Have a look at the magento wiki: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Yes i know this function, but in this case i think "addAttributeToSort" doesn't solves the problem. I dont want to sort by DESC oder ASC :(

Comment: Sorry, nicht ordentlich gelesen. Du möchtest ja nach Jahreszeit sortieren. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('cat_index_position','ASC');;        
$products->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("CASE WHEN `cat_index_position` = '0' THEN 9999 ELSE `cat_index_position` END"));
```

for me, this answer worked,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121234/71417